# Installing New Dishwasher in Old House

Tags: plumbing, appliances

I live in a house built in the 1970s. I tried to buy a new Bosch Ascenta dish washer. The installer from Best Buy who came by said that they couldn't install it because the pipes in our house are too big and the hoses from the dish washer are designed for newer plumbing with smaller pipes. He said I would have to call a plumber to resolve the issue. The pipes under the sink are copper. Are all new dish washers this way? I can pick a different brand if it'd help. I then called a plumber and they said they don't install dish washers! It feels like an impossible situation because unless I somehow got them to both show up at the same time, I'd be stuck without a dish washer for a while and there would be no way to test it while they're here. My old dishwasher is still working, but just leaks water and I can't close the detergent dispenser. I figured it'd be best to get a new one instead of repairing the old one. Any ideas?

Comment: The guy from the store sounds like he only knows how to 'plug and play' type.  All you probably need is adapters on the pipes.  These days quite a few are push connect types, so no need for soldering either.  All a person needs to know are the sizes.  Try a real appliance repair place.

Comment: I would call a different plumber. I'm surprised you found one that won't take that work; down-sizing pipes will take 15 minutes and they'll charge you triple digits.

Comment: As mentioned adaptors aren't hard to install. If you add a few pix and dimensions of what you're dealing with you might get a better answer here.

Comment: The Best Buy employee is not a plumber so I would definitely not want them touching my plumbing if I were you. The plumber's response is absolutely baffling and sounds like a person I wouldn't want touching my plumbing either. Call another plumber and explain you need your pipes adapted for a dishwasher. Even if you have galvanized steel piping it should be trivial to add an adapter assuming the pipes are coming out of the floor or are facing sideways.

Comment: @crip659 "The guy from the store sounds like he only knows how to 'plug and play' type." Is this a bad thing? You would prefer for a, usually apathetic, electronics store employee to perform plumbing in your home?

Comment: Some pictures of the setup would be nice.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus   Would at least hope that the guy can say I need to get these adapters/parts to install the dishwasher, not need new pipes.  Myself would only have them load it on my pickup.

Comment: @crip659 The Best Buy installer never said that. I think you should re-read the post. Per OP: "He said I would have to call a plumber to resolve the issue." and this is absolutely the correct response.

Comment: Copper pipes 3/4” easy 1/2” even easier may be time for you to learn some basic plumbing and if you don’t want to learn about soldering read up on shark bites. How is your existing DW plumbed ?

Comment: On a lot of dishwashers, there are 3 pipes - hot and cold in, waste water out. Which are you referring to? Also, the inlet will have a screw on fitting, which will need to be connected to a male fitting on the house pipes. Also, the outlet can be just like that on a washing machine (in fact all 3 are) and just push into a waste pipe, which *needs* to be bigger. Knowing what size existing pipes are is crucial to the question. Edit? Once again, location clues would help. House pipes could be just about anything!